# How to use Auth class to check role in laravel config file?

Tags: laravel, adminlte

I am using adminlte for my laravel app. And would like to create custom side menubar by checking user role. So how to use Auth class in adminlte.php config file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to filter your routes for different users https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware or use authorization to assign roles and cab used in controllers https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization